# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''

Tags: php

At the risk of getting a down vote I am going to ask this question to see if anyone can help me.  I have been staring at this for a while and I can't figure it out.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line 130

```
function pdf($type=null){                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    //get default or create a type                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    $data = $this->storeSessionData(                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        array(),                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        'SalesComp',                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $this->variables                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    $type = ($type)? $type : $data['type']; //this is line 130                                                                                                                                                                                            

    $this->set('data', $this->report('store', 'year', 3, $type));                                                                                                                                                                      

    $this->set(                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        'districtTitle',                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        array('N' => 'North', 'S' => 'South')                                                                                                                                                                                          
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $districts = $this->Store->find(                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        'list',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        array(                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            'fields' => array('Store', 'District'),                                                                                                                                                                                    
            'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('District'=> 'O')                                                                                                                                                                     
            )                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $this->set('districts', $districts);                                                                                                                                                                                               
    $supervisor = $this->Store->find(                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        'list',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        array('fields' => array('Store','Supervisor'),                                                                                                                                                                                 
              'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('District'=> 'O')                                                                                                                                                                   
              )                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $this->set('supervisor', $supervisor);                                                                                                                                                                                             

    $this->set(                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        'supervisors',                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        $this->Supervisor->find(                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            'list',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            array('fields' => array('Supervisor','ShortName')                                                                                                                                                                          
            )                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $title = ($type == 'sales')?                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        'Sales Comparison Report':'Fuel Comparison Report';                                                                                                                                                                            
    $this->set('title', $title);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    $this->layout = 'pdf';                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    $this->render();                                                                                                                                                                                                                   


}
```

Comment: Which line in this corresponds to line 130? Could be helpful

Comment: the one marked //this line is 130

Comment: Ah, I see. Wasn't checking the comments in the code...

Comment: cannot reproduce any error here. (maybe some invisible chars?)

Comment: No worries  =)  I just appreciate the help.

Comment: @NicholasSmith Don't see any parse error here: http://3v4l.org/ZtEdL

Comment: It may have something to do with all the excess whitespace at the end of the lines. I've seen it break heredoc strings before...

Comment: Your code is LITERALLY littered with TONS of whitespace. (e.g. edit the text here and you'll see how badly mangled the raw text looks). I'd suggest cleaning up the original code to remove all that whitespace and see what happens.

Comment: maybe the classical non breaking space : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
rewrite the entire line

Comment: @Marc B  I have a hard time believing that.  My Emacs is set up to destroy extra whitespace and replace the needed whitespace with space character

Comment: well, try to edit your question here. you'll see there's a TON of whitespace.

Comment: Whats the value of `$data['type']`?

Comment: However, I do believe that.  I will try.  Thanks

Comment: @alexP its a string like 'store'

Comment: @AlexP, @NicholasSmith: `$data['type']` cannot have a value because it is a **parse error**. The code is never executed.

Comment: The error suggests there are mismatched quotes somewhere. If you're using Emacs, use `M-x find-unbalanced-parentheses`. And if you have syntax highlighting enabled, you should be able to see the wrong colors.

Comment: @Barmar is right and wrong it was an unbalanced bracket

Comment: @Barmar I knew the experts could figure it out  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests mismatched quotes or brackets somewhere. Unfortunately, when this happens, the line number in the error message may be some totally unrelated line -- it's just the first place where the compiler notices that the syntax is no longer valid. The error is actually somewhere before the code snippet in the question, so it's impossible for me to pinpoint it. Syntax highlighting in code editors can help in finding the mismatch.

Comment: I finally found the error it was a mismatched quote in the previous function so Barmar is completely right.  My emacs syntax did not pick up the mismatch for whatever reason.  However, I fired up eclipse and it picked it up right away.  I am not sure what that says for the Emacs verses Eclipse debate but all is well that ends well.  I want to thank everyone for there help.

Comment: Emacs has long had problems with PHP because of the way it's mixed with HTML.

Comment: This is a different conversation for a different thread but there is no html in that page.  It really doesn't have any excuse.  However, I have to say it usually catches errors.  Well it doesn't catch them so much as not format correctly and I notice them.  Additionally, I love the way it formats my code.  I use a lot of closure type idioms and it steps the code very well.  Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all php tokens here:

http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

There's 2 things about the marked line:

1. PHP is a scripted language with a VERY complicated syntax in reality. It might look simple, but in comparison to C or the like it's very complicated, and only because there where so many small (and many times incoherent) changes made over the years, and some things can't be changed anymore without breaking backwards compatibility. One of those things is handling of parantheses - PHP does not handle these in a mathematical way, but treat them specially depending on context. This means you should get rid of them in the marked line (there is no need for them in the first place either way)
2. "Invisible" (i.e. UTF8) whitespaces - these are source for many "strange" problems, especially if you develop on a mac (press alt + space). Easiest way to fix them: Retype the line. And DON'T try copy & pasting it, because you will copy the whitespace as well.

Also I would change the line to

if (! $type) $type = $data['type'];

I hope you know which values evaluate falsy in php, because it's not only NULL (you can find a list here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php )

On a sidenote: PHP was developed as a simple way to write templates, so maybe you might want to have a look at some *compiled* programming languages if you want to build complex logic (C for example, which is *by far* simpler than PHP, and I've been doing PHP for more than 6 years now)

Comment: if (! $type) $type = $data['type']; did not work.  Still getting an error and I have delete the space in between the code with no luck

Comment: If it doesn't work, add linebreaks. You can break at nearly every position, and it will give you a more accurate error position. E.g. go through the lines before 130, 130, and the ones after, and break them apart onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$type = ($type)? $type : $data['type'];
```

With

```
$type = $type ? $type : $data['type'];
```

I doubt that it makes any difference, but maybe a space between the variable named `$type` and the question mark is needed. For more information about this, check the [PHP](http://php.net/) docs on the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: No it made no difference

Comment: @NicholasSmith also remove and retype the lines before and after line 130. Your editor might be confused, and display a wrong line as line 130.

Comment: @dialer If you don't know anything about this form of PHP, then you shouldn't be commenting

Comment: @DarylGill What is your problem? Either Emacs *or* the PHP interpreter might interpret a particular whitespace character, such as a sole `\r`, as a newline, adding to the line count, while the other one does not, thus resulting in a different line number for interpreter and editor.

Comment: Actually, @dialer is correct here. The editor might be reporting an error for a different line so make sure there's no whitespaces confusing it.

Comment: 1. While the editor might be reporting the error, going by the message, it is most probably generated by the PHP runtime. 2. I've never ever seen an editor in my past 15 years of programming which is being "confused by whitespaces" - \n is a newline and always will be. \r is carriage return, and while sometimes you might encounter \r\n (http spec for example) or even \n\r, \n always is a newline. Of course the editor is just another piece of software and might virtually do anything, but I doubt that the OP would've gotten that far in that case ;)

Comment: You can have a PHP statement stretched across several lines, and thus for example if you miss out on a ; at the end of a line you will get an error reported on the next line with code most of the time - but there is no "confusing whitespaces" involved there.